# How to get time zone format with GMT in Android device?

Tags: android, timezone

TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName(), I wanna get time zone name with GMT format ,like GMT-07:00，not PST or other format

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ZonedDateTime` in [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) to get the GMT/UTC offset time.

```
   val zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(
                    ZoneId.systemDefault())       //get system default time zone 
   Log.d("Date:", "Zone ${zonedDateTime.offset}") // A time-zone offset from Greenwich/UTC.
   // use zonedDateTime.zone to get zone id. Asia/Calcutta in this case
```

**Output:**   +05:30

**Note:** `ZonedDateTime` only works in android 8 and above, to use it below android 8 [enable desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring)